# Error: Can not process JOIN, call in session after previous JOIN

Tags: javascript, sinch

I have an error with Sinch `Error: Can not process JOIN, call in session after previous JOIN` Basically, the call drops when in progress. Here's a screenshot of the error console.

[image]

Here's another console dump of the same problem.

[image]

Has anyone seen that bug? What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Just click on Sinch.js at 5438 or 4692 and check the source?

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have this problem too I've found the solution. Sometimes I do development on my computer while it's offline so for dev purposes, I need all the client files available locally. I had stored the `sinch.js` file on my server in July and wasn't using the latest version in my code. I've corrected this problem by adding a reference to the online cdn version of the file and it all works again.